# Best way to schedule a NodeJS process on GCP that takes more than 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, cron

I have a nightly batch load job (14.7 million records)into a mySQL table, we have been using the GCP cron, but it occasionally times out. Do you have any suggestions or best practice tips for this type of scheduled process?  We are using the following sql statements:

- delete from
- Load data local infile

Our time is greatly reduced if we use a truncate statement rather than a delete, however with truncate we cannot rollback if there is a problem with the load.

Comment: Scheduled jobs that run nightly that are vital may be candidates for running using Cloud Composer (managed Apache Airflow).  I think we want to avoid the "glue" (i.e. scheduling when the job is to run) from impacting the operation (the job running).

Comment: If the answer below solved your question, kindly consider upvoting it as the community will find the answer very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

2 parts in your question:

- firstly, cloud scheduler can handle task up to 30 minutes. Therefore, if you use Cloud Run to run your script, you are no longer limited to 9 minutes as you are with Cloud Functions (if my assumption is the right one)
- Secondly, I can recommend, if it's possible in your database, to start by loading the data into a temporary table. if the load is OK, truncate your table and insert select the data from the temporary table to the target table.

Comment: I'll investigate how we might move from GCP cron to Cloud Run >  Cloud Scheduler.  I'm not too sure about the value of loading a temp table if I have the loadfile available.